# Is it possible to add multiple testplans in a testrun in Kiwi TCMS?

Tags: testing, testcase, kiwi-tcms

we want to use Kiwi to organize our testcases.
We have collected test cases in different subject areas and organised them in the testplans.
Now we want to combine the collected testplans into one testrun. But when creating a new testrun, we can only add 1 testplan.
Is there any way to add multiple testplans there?

We added all our test cases to a test run, but there are more than 600....
Our Expectation ist to define a test plan with a number of test cases and define a test run with these test plans.